# REST disregards any part that is not English characters , when receiving UTF-8

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, rest, utf-8

Sending ajax request in UTF8 to the server that uses REST , disregards any part that is not English characters

I'm using JAVA with REST on the server side , and the client sends ajax requests in UTF8 , that includes Hebrew words .

The AJAX request :

```
var clientNumber  = '12344432432';
var userID = '321321321';
var someHebrewWord = ...;
var someEnglishWord  = ....;

var servletUrl = '/Management/services/manager/' + clientNumber + '/' + userID + '/' + someEnglishWord + '/' someHebrewWord;
alert('Sending this :' + servletUrl);
$.ajax({ 
    url: servletUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false, 
    data: { }, 
    success: function(data){
        alert('Return value is:' + data);
        window.location = "./replyPage.html";
    }
    , error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
        alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err + " " + JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    }
});
```

On the server side , I use REST :

```
@Produces({ "application/json" })
@Path("/manager")
public class Management {


    @POST
    @Path("{clientNumber }/{userID }/{someEnglishWord}/{someHebrewWord}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public boolean insert(@PathParam("clientNumber") String clientNumber, @PathParam("userID") String userID,
                              @PathParam("someEnglishWord") String someEnglishWord, @PathParam("someHebrewWord") String someHebrewWord) 
    {
        // do some stuff 
    }


    @POST
    @Path("{clientNumber }/{userID }/{someEnglishWord}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public boolean updateSomething(@PathParam("clientNumber") String clientNumber, @PathParam("userID") String userID , @PathParam("someEnglishWord") String someEnglishWord)

    {
        // do other stuff
    }   



    // more code 

}
```

So , when the AJAX request is sent , the `updateSomething()` is invoked instead of `insert()` , 
even though I'm sending 4 fields , and not 3 !

What causes this , and how can I fix it ?

Much appreciated

Comment: So what will you do when you receive the following text "I'd like to introduce myself.  Attached is a copy of my résumé".  Does that not qualify as "English".  My point is that there is no such thing as English vs non-English characters.  English borrows from many languages and you are likely to encounter "non-English" characters in a valid English sentence.

Comment: @JimGarrison: I'm meaning that if I'd send instead of `I'd like to introduce myself. Attached is a copy of my résumé` , this : `שלום אני רוצה להציג את עצמי ומסמך קורות החיים שלי מצורף` , then the code that would be INVOKED is `updateSomething` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowed characters in a URL is restricted. You have to encode the URL with [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

A better option might be posting those parameters in a data -variable and using @FormParam instead of @PathParam.